# ２つのRailsアプリケーション間でセッションを共有したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cookie, session

この投稿は下記ページの転載です。
https://teratail.com/questions/61778

---

Rails3で稼働しているアプリケーションをRails5にアップデートしようと思っています。

Rails5のプロジェクトを新規作成し、現状のアプリケーションと同じサーバー内で２つを並行稼動させ、Nginx側でURLによるルーティングをすることで徐々に5へ移行していくような計画をたてています。

静的なページはこれでうまく動いているのですが、ログインが必要なページでセッションが共有されず困っています。

Rails3とRails4以降ではセッション暗号化の仕組みが変わっているようなので、下記の記事を参考に設定を行いました。

https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails/3-steps-to-share-a-session-between-rails-3-and-rails-4-applications-9618766e6c2a#.udvo3a58p

1. 新旧Railsでセッションストアの設定を統一

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'example.net_session'
```

2. Rails5のcookie形式をjsonからmarshalに変更

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal # default: :json
```

3. Rails5のsecret_key_baseの設定を消し、代わりにsecret_tokenを設定

secret_tokenはRails3のconfig.secret_token と同じ値です

```
development:
  # secret_key_base: abc123...
  secret_token: 123abc...
```

4. Deviseのsecret_keyを設定

これも新旧Railsで共通の値を入れています

```
Devise.setup do |config| 
  config.secret_key = "xyz123"
  ~~~
end
```

設定は以上です。

ローカルで2つのRails(WEBrickとPuma)をdocker内で立ち上げ、本番と同じようにNginxでURLによってproxy_passを振り分けるという方法でテストしています。

Rails3側でログインし、次にRails5側で実装済みのページに移動するとcookieが書き換えられてしまい、非ログイン状態に戻ってしまいます。

他に試すべきこと、確認事項などあれば些細な事でも結構ですので、助言を頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10150

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/61778

Comment: 失礼しました。マルチポストである旨を追加しました。
いずれかのサイトで解答が得られた場合、それぞれのサイトで報告するつもりでしたが、もし規約としてマルチポストというだけでNGの対象であればご指導頂けると助かります。

Comment: マルチポストが禁止されているわけではありませんが、もし先に他のサイトで回答が得られましたら、回答にその内容を転記して投稿してください。それから48時間たつと、自身の回答を承認できるようになります。承認すると質問が解決済みになります。

Comment: stackoverflowはマルチポストについて特にルールはないです。回答者が他のサイトの回答状況を確認しやすいようにコメントしているだけです。なお、teratailには「推奨しない」「理由を書く、リンクを貼る」というルールがあるそうです。 https://teratail.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

セッションが共有できなかった原因は、Rails3の方でdevise-encryptableを導入していたからでした。解決方法は下記になります。

Rails5のGemfileに`devise-encryptable`を追加し`bundle install`

Rails5の`app/models/user.rb`のdeviseオプションに`:encryptable`を追加

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :encryptable
end
```

Rails5の`config/initializers/devise.rb`に、Rails3の方と同じ暗号化方式を設定

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.encryptor = :sha512
```

以上で、２つのアプリケーション間でログイン状態を共有できるようになりました。